# Is PhoneGap suited for developing shopping site?

Tags: cordova

I'm developing a shopping site‘s mobile client.Its main function is marked on the map merchants, and provides a list display of goods (including commodity picture) provides online ordering capabilities.I chose PhoneGap, do not know the wisdom of this decision?Who can tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is *possible* to create the type of app you are talking about with phone gap, but you have to look at a few fundamentale pros and cons, and see how they affect you, in order to make a wise choice. Here are a few:

**Pros:**

- You will be able to almost imidiatly distrebute your app on most major appstores (iOS app store, google play, etc.). So you don't have to rewrite your app for every OS.
- Phone gap development is much easier than Native development, and doesn't require half the time / resources / knowledge.
- Many more HTML / JS / CSS developers out there for phone gap. Native developers are rarer and much pricier.

**Cons:**

- The user expierience achived by phonegap will never much the one achived by a native app. Aspecially in an app like yours which requires a lot of graphice (for the maps). While UX (user experience) and Responsivnes might not seem as important, it is actually one of the most important factors of making a good app.
- With Phonegap, you only get limited access to device capabilities, so advanced fetures the phone has might not be accessible to you. That mioght also limit future development and addition of features to the app.

As a summery, it is possible to make do with phone gap, but i truly recommend to invest the additional time and money to develop a native app, so you will get a **PERFECT**, responsive app!

Comment: In fact, this is a commissioned development projects, regardless of time or money is very tight.If I make the wrong decision, it may make the project fail, so that my clients have suffered losses.I was wondering: Can we use the map part of the native program?This phoneGap with Object_C integrated precedent it?

Comment: I believe there is a way to create a custom native plug-in to phone-gap, and you can look around the net and probably find a couple of map plugins, but creating your own plugin is very complex. As I said in my answer, my recommendation is to go native and create a GREAT app, not a mediocre one. What OS(s) are you targeting?

Comment: IOS 5.0.In Displaying map, PhoneGap can achieve a not bad user experience?I do not have much choice.

Comment: In detail, client server will send me some latitude and longitude information, I have to do is put these points marked on the google map.Then the map displayed.This work, PhoneGap is not suitable for competent?

Comment: The thing with phone gap is that it is stored as a website on the device which the app is running on, and rendered out as a website within the app. Think of the UX of a phone gap app like using a website, just without the time it takes for a page to load. It is alright, but not perfect. Also, try addressing iOS 6 and not 5, as it came out 3 days ago and already accounts for 30% of iOS users

Comment: Really thank you for your patience to answer.This software release in China, there are a lot of iphone4 user, so my customer requirements based ios5.0 development.I can imagine it running, but can not confirm the speed of its response.This makes me a headache.

Comment: I'm learning how to operate.So that is the point of it?

Comment: yes pretty much :) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I tested in open map, phoneGap the obvious inferior, especially in the frequent switching between list and map.But in other parts of the program than the native and no significant differences.Do I really have to do it yourself to write a map plug?Afraid not enough time.

Comment: No you could obviously use a pre written map plugin for PhoneGap. You could also use the following project to use the native MapKit in Your phone gap app: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/MapKitPlug

Answer (score 1):

Because you are thinking of PhoneGap, I assume you target more than one platform.

With all respect to byteSlayer (I agree with his comments), I don't think you will heavily need the device capabilities. Therefore, I would prefer to use PhoneGap instead of investing money (or time) for development in native platform in each platform.

I also don't think there is a security concern for Phonegap. Javascript code is in clear text, but XCode is easy to re-engineer as well. [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) will never works, btw. On the other hand, you already have a website, where you deliver content to user in clear text (html, js etc.) I assume your app structure will be based on a client-server architecture, which is not that different than a user requests web pages from your server.

Comment: Yes I already have a website.This work is move it onto iphone4/4s, nothing more.I like  it :"Security through obscurity will never works".Very insightful summary.I hope soon will be able to share with you the results of my test, I have 2-3 days to test the the map module's performance to decide whether to use the map plug-in or other.Thank you very much!